# Getting first row by ID in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a piece of code that should be getting the `first_team` (first value) of a column grouped by ID and setting it to a dictionary, but what I am seeing is it is only getting the first value with value. Excluding those that are NaN.

Here is a sample dataset

```
 ID     date           name       team       first_team
 101   05/2012         James      NaN            NY
 101   07/2012         James      NY             NY
 102   06/2013         Adams      NC             NC
 102   05/2014         Adams      AL             NC
```

The code I have is:

```
first_dict = df.groupby('ID').agg({'team':'first'}).to_dict()['team']
df['first_team'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: first_dict[x])
```

Desired output:

```
  ID      date        name      team         first_team 
  101     05/2012     James      NaN           NaN 
  101     07/2012     James      NY            NaN 
  102     06/2013     Adams      NC            NC 
  102     05/2014     Adams      AL            NC
```

Comment: Note that they're not "NA", as in "not applicable", they're "NaN", suggesting they are a string representation of "this is not a number even though it was supposed to be" value, and something already went wrong during the generation of that sample data.

Comment: From [`DataFrameGroupBy.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-first): **Compute the first non-null entry of each column.** So it skips the `NaN` values to find the first.

Comment: @Barmar okay I see that now thank you is there a awy to use groupby finding NaNs or will I have to us loc?

Comment: The funny thing about NaN is that it's never equal to itself, so I'd expect grouping on it to be wonky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the first entry, you can do with `drop_duplicates`:

```
first_dict = df.drop_duplicates('ID')[['ID','team']].set_index('ID')['team']
df['first_team'] = df['ID'].map(first_dict)
```

Output:

```
    ID     date   name team first_team
0  101  05/2012  James  NaN        NaN
1  101  07/2012  James   NY        NaN
2  102  06/2013  Adams   NC         NC
3  102  05/2014  Adams   AL         NC
```

**Note**: FFR, your code can be better done with `transform`,

```
df['first_team'] = df.groupby('ID')['team'].transform('first')
```